# c# HttpClient. Why am I getting Unauthorized, when Postcall works (bearer token)

Tags: c#, rest, http

I wrote this call:

```
public static async Task<List<Buildings>> GetBuildings(string token)
        {
            var url = baseUrl + "buildings";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);


            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                List<Buildings> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Buildings>>(content);
                return res;
            }
            else
                return new List<Buildings>(); 
        }
```

Copying this postman

[image]

However, the C# call is returned as unauth.

I am using the right token, that I just received from the server a second ago.

I have noticed that the actual header looks like this:

[image]

Which is a bit different from what postman does with it calling it "bearer" instand of "bearer token"

But the word token is added automatically by the function.

Can you help me out here?

EDIT:

Alternativly,

when I do:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer", token);
```

The header looks like this:

[image]

So again is the word "TOKEN" added, event with a ":" in between...

EDIT 2:

I have also noticed the return is not unauth but :
"JWT Token not found"

So I am guessing, its the way the token is transmitted...

Comment: Perhaps the string value passed as the `token` argument is `"Token: eyJ0e..."`?

Comment: Maybe try `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, value);` replicating key and value based on the values on Postman. It allows you to manually remove `"Token"`.

Comment: @anastaciu I tried that first, but still it is converted into Bearer TOKEN, it justs adds the word TOKEN...

Comment: There is no problem between postman's bearer interpretation and C#'s bearer interpretation. AFAI understand, Unauth means you got authorization but not authentication.

Comment: @innom, that doesn't seem right, the `value` should be the exact string you pass as argument.

Comment: @anastaciu please see my edit...

Comment: @innom I meant `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Comment: As @MathiasR.Jessen wrote: can you check in the debugger if the value in the `token` parameter starts with "TOKEN: "? Seems to be the only reason why this could happen. You can check the source code of `AuthenticationHeaderValue` at https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/AuthenticationHeaderValue.cs

Comment: I a sorry, please see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct, the token was wrong and another class added the word "token" infront of it, ofc making the token be not found.. .:( sorry.